# Invalid Argument error when using launchctl load with bsexec

Tags: macos, unix, launchd

Any thoughts on how to load a plist with current user privileges as root from the command line?

I am currently managing 30 remote OSX machines. I have decided to use Remote Desktop to make updates to a /Library/LaunchAgent plist file on each machine. As each machine will require a unique update, I am loath to do this at each machine as the current logged-in user. I am making updates as the root user over remote desktop. My desire is to stop the plist using `launchctl`, update the plist, and restart the plist.

My process is this:

1. Unload the /Library/LaunchAgent plist as root using `launchtl bsexec PID launchctl unload /Library/LaunchAgents/plist`.  The `bsexec PID` argument allows the root user to unload a plist that is managed by a non-root `launchd` process. This works successfully.
2. I will then update the plist on each computer as root. This works fine as well.
3. Lastly, I need to restart the /Library/LaunchAgent plist using `launchctl`. This is where my process breaks down. I can not launch my plist using `launchctl bsexec PID load /Library/LaunchAgents/plist` -- I receive an invalid argument error.

Any thoughts on how to restart the service with current user privileges as root?

Comment: Sharing the full error message may increase your chances of a helpful response.

Comment: Thanks. The full error is: "Invalid argument". This is returned from the command line. Very terse.

Comment: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/loath is the adjectival form of the word

Comment: I stand corrected on both counts.

Answer (score 0):

Try add 'sudo' before second launchctl

```
sudo launchctl bsexec PID sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/Your.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is still relevant (it is to me), I hope this answer helps:

```
$sudo launchctl bsexec PID /usr/bin/sudo -u USER /bin/launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/com.example.agent.plist
```

This way it works for me, loads the agent in correct bootstrap without errors.

kbai